# Array JLabel ActionListener multiple JPanels

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have an array of JLabels and I want to add an ActionListener to them. Every label should display a panel and the other should be removed. How can I realize this?

Comment: Don't just ask us to write code for you.  Please post your work-in-progress implementation.

Comment: I don't need a code only how to do. Should I create methods for the single panels? Then add in the mouseListener an if case? Like if case1: lable.getText()=xy then call methode xy, ect ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly add an `ActionListener` to a `JLabel` - it doesn't have that functionality. Instead, you should create a `MouseAdapter`, override the `mouseClicked` method, and use `JLabel.addMouseListener` to add it to your `JLabel`s. The best way to get it to, as you say, "display a panel and the other should be removed" would be to use a `CardLayout`.

Comment: Or use an undecorated JButton and get keyboard support as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

> I have an array of JLabels and I want to add an ActionListener to
>   them.

`JLabel` doesn't have `ActionListener` support. You can use a undecorated `JButton` instead

> Every label should display a panel and the other should be removed.
>   How can I realize this?

Use a `CardLayout`